# Filter Web Part disappear

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I'm learning Sharepoint using SHareopint 2013 Foundation, 
When trying to test [this guide](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-a-Filter-Web-Part-to-a-List-View-Web-Part-on-a-classic-page-4f3f6c10-0a1b-479d-8b4d-c4f1bf49bb3f) about filter web part, I can't access to this feature cause I can't see it, 
this is screen shot in guide 
[image]
But on my PC, there is no "Filter" in Categories
[image]
What did I do wrong? How can I fix it?
Update: 
Enterprise feature (Site collection level) is not appeared in Site Setting.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Filter webparts are not available in SharePoint Foundation and Standard Edition. They are part of SharePoint Enterprise edition.

I faced this issue, in one of our SharePoint Standard edition implementation. What I done is, copied filter webpart file from enterprise edition and uploaded in standard edition. And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Check Enterprise feature (Site collection level) is activated or not.

[image]

Comment: I updated my question, this feature is not appeared too :(

Comment: [Missing](http://getadmins.blogspot.in/2012/10/missing-sharepoint-server-enterprise.html) **Or** Try this [Missing SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection Features in Site collection Feature](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/9c9c5baf-2ded-4a34-bf73-2616c2fb34a7/missing-sharepoint-server-enterprise-site-collection-features-in-site-collection-feature?forum=sharepointadminlegacy&forum=sharepointadminlegacy)